# ¿Cómo puedo limitar la entrada de caracteres con la función input()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿Cómo se puede limitar la entrada de X número de caracteres con la función `input`?

Por ejemplo si se desea capturar a través de `input` un máximo de 2 caracteres:

```
a = int(input(" Ingrese la Calificacion No 1:"))
```

Al ejecutar input permite ingresar cualquier cantidad de números.

Answer (score 1):

Esto pasa porque `stdin` es line-buffered o *alineado en linea* y no dejara de leer hasta que ingreses un caracter de salto de linea `'\n'` *(`'\r\n'` en Windows)*.

Si se te permite *"Truncar"* la entrada recibida, te convendría hacerlo, aplicado a tu código sería algo como:

```
a = int(input(" Ingrese la Calificacion No 1:")[0:2])
```

Al ejecutarlo, produce la siguiente salida:

```
>>> a = int(input(" Ingrese la Calificacion No 1:")[0:2])
 Ingrese la Calificacion No 1:325
>>> a
32
```

> Si lo que se necesita es validar que la entrada se encuentra dentro de un rango de números, entonces, es mas conveniente realizar la comparación luego de introducir el valor y si es necesario, realizar algún ciclo hasta que el valor se encuentre dentro del rango.

Espero te haya ayudado, saludos!

Answer (score -1):

Esta podría ser la respuesta:

```
a = int(input(" Ingrese la Calificacion No 1:", maxlength=2))
a = int(input(" Ingrese la Calificacion No 1:").maxlength(2))
```

Pero maxlength no esta implementado.

Sería buena idea comentarlo con el mantenedor y/o desarrollador de la función input() en Python.

Esta otra también podría ser otra respuesta:

```
a = maxlength(2)
a = int(input(" Ingrese la Calificacion No 1:"))
```

O esta:

```
a=int.maxlength(2)
```

Yo también ando detrás de encontrar alguna solución fácil, pero parece imposible.

Salud!

Jac.

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta, ya que no resuelve el problema. por favor lea [answer]